# Can $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (1-\frac {x_i}{\sqrt{x_i^2+r^2}}) \cdot (x_{i+1}-x_{i})$ be written as a definite integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left (1-\frac {x_i}{\sqrt{x_i^2+r^2}}\right) \cdot (x_{i+1}-x_{i})$$

$x_1=1$, $x_n=a+L$

I don't really see a way to manipulate this into a desirable form, but I have about zero experience doing this so I am probably wrong.

This sum came up when I was trying to find the electric field caused by a cylinder.

Comment: Electric field caused by a cylinder where? What kind of cylinder?

Comment: I ask because there might be a more tractable way around that.

Comment: Also,last question. What is the relation between $x_{i+1}$ and $x_i$

Comment: Just a regular horizontal cylinder with it's axis on the x-axis. It has radius r, volume density $\row$length $L$, charge $Q$. The point I am trying to find the electric field at is on the x-axis, a units away from the cylinder

Comment: I was trying to convince myself that the electric field is 0 at the point as illustrated in a picture I saw. It's completely counterintuitive to me that E should be 0 at that point. I was thinking the electric field lines would come out of the sides just as they do off the curved surface

Comment: I assume the $x_{i+1}-x_i$ approach $0$. The $\sum (1)(x_{i+1}-x_i)$ might as well be treated separately, it is $a+L-1$. The rest (well, the whole thing too) is a Riemann sum for the integral from $1$ to $a+L$ of $-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2}}$.

Comment: Okay. Volume density $\rho$ of mass or charge?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes it would approach $0$, and thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Sabyasachi of charge. I split the cylinder into many disks who's width approaches 0

Comment: @Sabyasachi so that I could use the formula for electric field for a disk, which contains surface density. I got the $x_{i+1}-x_{i}$ from the sigma.

Comment: @Ovi okay. Seems like Andre already solved the integral itself. I will try to come up with some physics solution for this and post. It's my stronger suit.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Ok thanks

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you post the solution and the proccess as an answer? I didn't learn how to convert sums to integrals in class, I just watched a short video about it and from the video I don't see how you did this.

Comment: @Ovi the idea is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=na}^{r=nb}f(\frac{r}{n}) = \int_a^bf(x)\,dx$$

Comment: after that it is a matter of finding suitable $f(x)$.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Hmm that's interesting, it looks very different from the video but this form is probably more useful.

Comment: @Ovi I made a typo. Check it now.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Ok I see, but it seems a little constricted because it is only using equal intervals in the Riemann sum I think

Comment: I expect someone will post an answer, have done too many recently. Things may look more familiar if you specialize to $x_{i+1}-x_i=\frac{b-a}{n}$ where $[a,b]$ is the interval.

Comment: @Ovi this [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/105635/127574) answer might help. The illustration makes the sum come *alive*

Comment: @Sabyasachi Hey can you join the chat room "Conversation between Ovi and Sabyasachi"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The following general result helps to see why:

*Let $\mathcal{P}=\lbrace a=x_1<x_2<x_3<\cdots<x_n=b\rbrace$ be a partition; and $f$ a function defined on $[a,b]$ for any choice of $s_i\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ the sum $$\mathcal{S}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(s_i) \cdot (x_{i+1}-x_{i})$$ is a Riemann sum of $f$ associated to the partition $\mathcal{P}$.*

*Let $f$ be integrable in the sense of Riemann on the interval $[a,b]$ and $\mathcal{P}_n$ be a sequence of partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n} \mid\mid P_n\mid\mid=0$. If for every $n$ we consider a Riemann sum associated to the partition $\mathcal{(P)}_n$ and to the function $f$, then
$$\displaystyle\lim_n \mathcal{S}_n=\int_a^{b} f$$*

---

Then considering the partition $\mathcal{P}_n=\lbrace a=x_1<x_2<x_3<\cdots<x_n=a+L\rbrace$  and $f(x)=1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2}}$, which is easy to see is continuous, hence integrable. Then we have,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left (1-\frac {x_i}{\sqrt{x_i^2+r^2}}\right) \cdot (x_{i+1}-x_{i})=\int_a^{a+L} {1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2}}dx}$$
whenever the norm of the partition tends to zero, i.e. $\text{sup} \lbrace x_{i+1}-x_i \mid i=1,\ldots, n\rbrace \rightarrow 0$