# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$ is equal to

a) 0

b) 1

c)2

d)$\log_e2$

I am not getting how to deal with this limit,what should I use here. It is not in the form $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$also that I can use ceasaro theorem.

For any hint, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help needed with definite integral for $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105631/help-needed-with-definite-integral-for-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B2%7D%2B...%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2n%7D%24)

Comment: For this multiple-choice question you can also exclude a, b, c by showing that the limit must be strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score -2):

First, this limit, you can change the form like (1/n)[1/(1+1/n)+1/(1+2/n)+...+1/(1+n/n)], then this can be seen as an integral from 0 to 1, the integral 1/1+x, this integral is easy to solve.
Second,

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, don't answer a duplicated question.